# Duplicate post in multiple loops on wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, loops, post, duplicates

I am trying to create multiple loops in wordpress without any repeat post.
this is the code that I have now, where I have added in the first loop

```
<?php $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID?>
```

and i have added this in the rest of loops

```
<?php if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>
```

but still showing the post repeated,

please you can help me
thanks

here all of the code

```
<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

<!-- -------------------------1----------------------------- -->

<!--4 post de categoria news & what we do -->

<?php query_posts('cat=8,6,3,2&posts_per_page=4&orderby=rand'); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- contenido duplicado excluido loop principal-->

<?php $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>

    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <!-- <h1><?php the_title() ;?></h1> -->
    <!-- <?php the_excerpt(); ?> -->
    <!-- <span id="mas">Leer más</span> -->

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p>Sorry, there are no posts to display</p>

<?php endif; ?>



<!-- -------------------------2----------------------------- -->

<!--1 post de categoria video reciente -->

<?php rewind_posts(); ?>

<?php query_posts('category_name=articulo&showposts=1&post_type=post&orderby=date'); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- contenido duplicado excluido loop principal-->

<?php if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>

    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <!-- <h1><?php the_title() ;?></h1> -->
    <!-- <?php the_excerpt(); ?> -->
    <!-- <span id="mas">Leer más</span> -->

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p>Sorry, there are no posts to display</p>

<?php endif; ?>


<!-- -------------------------3----------------------------- -->

<!--4 post de categoria news & what we do -->

<?php rewind_posts(); ?>

<?php query_posts('cat=8,6,3,2&posts_per_page=4&orderby=rand'); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- contenido duplicado excluido loop principal-->
<?php if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>

    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <!-- <h1><?php the_title() ;?></h1> -->
    <!-- <?php the_excerpt(); ?> -->
    <!-- <span id="mas">Leer más</span> -->

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p>Sorry, there are no posts to display</p>

<?php endif; ?>

<!-- -------------------------4----------------------------- -->
<!--4 post de random de todo -->

<?php rewind_posts(); ?>

<?php query_posts('cat=8,6,3,2,1,4,5,9&posts_per_page=100&orderby=rand'); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- contenido duplicado excluido loop principal-->

<?php if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>

    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <!-- <h1><?php the_title() ;?></h1> -->
    <!-- <?php the_excerpt(); ?> -->
    <!-- <span id="mas">Leer más</span> -->

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p>Sorry, there are no posts to display</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code. The basic idea is to store the post ids that are displayed in an array. And while you are in any other loop on the page, Check whether the id exists in the array or not. If the id exists, it means we do not have to show the post.

```
<?php query_posts('cat=8,6,3,2&posts_per_page=4&orderby=rand'); ?>

<?php $ids_done = array();  ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- contenido duplicado excluido loop principal-->
$current_post_id = get_the_ID();

if( !in_array($current_post_id,$ids_done) ){ // display only if not a repeated post

    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <!-- <h1><?php the_title() ;?></h1> -->
    <!-- <?php the_excerpt(); ?> -->
    <!-- <span id="mas">Leer más</span> -->

}

<?php $ids_done[] = $current_post_id; ?>     

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p>Sorry, there are no posts to display</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```